# Flutter | How to check if String does not contain a substring or a character

Tags: string, flutter, dart, contains

I'm learning Flutter/Dart and there is this check that i want to perform - to validate that a user who has entered an email should contain @ in it

```dart
String myString = 'Dart';

// just like i can do the following check
myString.contains('a') ? print('validate') : print('does not validate')

// I want to do another check here
myString does not contain('@') ? print('does not validate'): print('validate')
```

Can someone suggest is there any inbuilt function to do such a thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just simply put not `!` operator (also known as `bang` operator on null-safety) on start

```
void main() {
  String myString = 'Dart';

// just like i can do the following check
  myString.contains('a') ? print('validate') : print('does not validate');

// I want to do another check here
  !myString.contains('@') ? print('does not validate') : print('validate');
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any inbuilt function for this.

Comment: Okk! So i can use this `bang` operator pretty much with everything

Comment: ```dart 

bool check = false;

!check ? print('getting the hang of it') : print('not yet');
```